# AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot' on vs code

Tags: discord

When I run my vs code I get this error:

main.py", line 40, in 
bot = discord.Bot()
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'

I am not totally sure what I have to change to get it to run either. Does someone happen to know what to do?

Python Version 3.7.9

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the code in question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.